# Remove all occurrences of a word from a string

Tags: string, bash, shell

I have the following string

```
str="toto1 toto2 toto3 toto4 toto2 toto5"
```

the `toto2` occurs twice in the string. How can I remove all `toto2` occurrences from the string?

I tried this:

```
echo ${str/toto2/}
```

But this will remove only the first occurrence of `toto2`.

```
toto1 toto3 toto4 toto2 toto5 # output
```

How can I remove all `toto2` occurrences from the string?

Comment: FYI, if you want a set abstraction in bash, it's better to use bash 4's associative arrays rather than strings for the purpose.

Comment: Vaguely related: [Bash string manipulation -- removing characters?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23047934/bash-string-manipulation-removing-characters) asks about trimming a temperature expression to just the actual floating-point number.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

[Found it.](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Shell-Parameter-Expansion.html) The solution is:

```
echo "${str//toto2/}"
```

Comment: @anishsane ABS is not a great reference -- it shows a lot of bad practices in its examples. Better to point folks at http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/073

Comment: I linked to the Bash reference manual, and added the missing quotes. See also [When to wrap quotes around a shell variable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10067266/when-to-wrap-quotes-around-a-shell-variable)