# What does ${1-1} in bash mean?

Tags: bash, osascript

I'm reading the scripts from [here](https://github.com/NapoleonWils0n/bashfinder/blob/master/.bash_macosx) and trying to understand what's going on. This function performs changing the directory of a Finder window:

```
function ee { 
 osascript -e 'set cwd to do shell script "pwd"'\
 -e 'tell application "Finder"'\
 -e "if (${1-1} <= (count Finder windows)) then"\
 -e "set the target of window ${1-1} to (POSIX file cwd) as string"\
 -e 'else' -e "open (POSIX file cwd) as string"\
 -e 'end if' -e 'end tell';\
};\
```

I'm assuming the `$` is interpreted by bash, since it's inside double-quotes. I haven't been able to find what could `{1-1}` mean. I've played with the expression in separate test scripts but couldn't find a difference from plain `$1`. Any ideas?

Comment: I *believe* it's a "default".  If the user supplied a command line argument then `${1-1}` would expand to that argument, otherwise it would simply expand/"default" to whatever was after the hypen -- in your case `1`.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

This means that if argument 1 (`${1}`) is not set, it will be set to 1.

See [parameter substitution here](http://tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/parameter-substitution.html).

```
 ${parameter-default}, ${parameter:-default}
   If parameter not set, use default.
```

Comment: +1, Just a note: I was suggested [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20783187/remove-a-word-from-a-string-in-bash-shell-linux/20783245#comment31159567_20783245) that, "ABS is not a great reference -- it shows a lot of bad practices in its examples. Better to point folks at mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/073 "

Comment: @anishsane thank you for the reference. The examples are really bad in tldp.org. But their layout is more concise IMHO.