# Using ${1:1} in bash

Tags: linux, bash, shell

does someone knows what `${1:1}` means in bash?

For example:

```
for (( i=0; $i < ${1:1}; i++ ))
do
    addToList $2
done
```

Comment: Not sure of the exact answer, but possible this other answer helps you out: http://stackoverflow.com/q/20836612/571237

Comment: @SamStorie Nope. That's something different.

Answer (score 5):

That's a bash [parameter expansion](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#Shell-Parameter-Expansion).

Specifically:

> ```
> ${parameter:offset}
> ${parameter:offset:length}
> ```
>
> This is referred to as Substring Expansion. It expands to up to length characters of the value of parameter starting at the character specified by offset. If parameter is ‘@’, an indexed array subscripted by ‘@’ or ‘*’, or an associative array name, the results differ as described below. If length is omitted, it expands to the substring of the value of parameter starting at the character specified by offset and extending to the end of the value. length and offset are arithmetic expressions (see Shell Arithmetic).
>
> Here are some examples illustrating substring expansion on parameters and subscripted arrays:
>
> ```
> $ string=01234567890abcdefgh
> $ echo ${string:7}
> 7890abcdefgh
> ```

So `${1:1}` is expand the substring of positional parameter `1` starting from the second character (`offset` of 1 unspecified `length`).

Presumably that is intended to support a script taking arguments something like this:

```
./addn -10 A
```

to add ten `A` elements to whatever `addToList` is adding to.

Though that's a poor way of handling that unless the argument has been checked before that for validity/sanity.

Answer (score 1):

See for yourself:

```
#!/bin/bash
for (( i=0; $i < ${1:1}; i++ ))
do
    echo $i ${1:1}
done
```

save this into a file named **test**. Now run this test like this:

```
./test 45
```

You will get output:

```
0 5
1 5
2 5
3 5
4 5
```

A little explanation what's happening:

you are using arithmetic for loop, so it expects an arithmetic value of `${1:1}` which is actually the second digit of you argument `45`.

`$(1:1}` just takes a string from index 1 from the first argument passed in command line and that's 5 for now. if you pass `a5` as the argument the output would still be the same. And thus `$i` is being looped through 5 times from 0 to 4.

So if you used `${2:1}`, it would expect a second argument i.e you would have to run the test like: `./test 34 455`

And this time it would take the value `55` from second argument which is the string from index 1 in this case.